# Github action get tiggered from a new issue opened against a repo

Tags: github-actions

Can you please tell me if it is possible to setup Github action which gets triggered
when a new issue opened against a repo?

If not, is there other way which I can automated when a new issue is filed in a repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forllowing the [GitHub workflow syntax for `on.<event_name>.types`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onevent_nametypes), you can trigger an action on a new issue with:

```
name: "Set Issue Label and Assignee"
on:
  issues:
  types: [opened]
```

Example: [`Naturalclar/issue-action`](https://github.com/Naturalclar/issue-action)

Webhooks are not needed here:

1. Subcribing to a [webhook event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks#events) like the [one for issues](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#issues) is not enough: you need to setup a listener which will process the JSON payload. (for instance, building a [GitHub App with ProBot](https://probot.github.io/docs/webhooks/)).
2. "if not": [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) are there to avoid using webhooks, if your project is on GitHub.com (webhooks can still be useful for on premise GitHub hosting servers for example)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to subscribe to this webhook.

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/event-payloads/#issues

```
Webhook payload object

Key    Type     Description
action  string  The action that was performed. Can be one of opened, edited, deleted, 
                pinned, unpinned, closed, reopened, assigned, unassigned, labeled, 
                unlabeled, locked, unlocked, transferred, milestoned, or demilestoned.
```